Deriving differential equation from difference of PDE solutions
This is an edited cross-post from Math SE because after several days it's received no good answer. I think it's less appropriate for a general QA Math site and is likely better for Overflow with heavier research focus.
Consider defining $$f(x,t)=g(x,t)-h(x,t)$$
The PDEs for $g(x,t)$ and $h(x,t)$ have the form
$$
\dfrac{dg}{dt}+a_1+a_2\dfrac{dg}{dx}+a_3\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}\right)^2+a_4\dfrac{d^2g}{dx^2}+a_5g=0
$$
$$
\dfrac{dh}{dt}+b_1+b_2\dfrac{dh}{dx}+b_3\left(\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)^2+b_4\dfrac{d^2h}{dx^2}+b_5h=0
$$
The solutions for $g(x,t)$ and $h(x,t)$ are known and are quadratic functions of $x$, via guess-and-check method and solving the reduced ODE system. Additionally note they have the same form but differ in coefficients.
QUESTION: Can the differential equation, and thus solution, of $f(x,t)$ be derived from knowing only the PDEs of $g(x,t)$ and $h(x,t)$ and not their solutions? This has implications for harder problems where solving the PDEs are impractical, but we want to recover something like $f(x,t)$ if possible.
MY ATTEMPT: Using a differential operator consistent with above PDEs, let
$$
\mathcal{D}(z)=c_0\dfrac{dz}{dt}+c_1+c_2\dfrac{dz}{dx}+c_3\left(\dfrac{dz}{dx}\right)^2+c_4\dfrac{d^2z}{dx^2}+c_5z
$$
Now applying $\mathcal{D}(z)$ to $f(x,t)$ and setting to 0,
$$
\mathcal{D}(f)=c_0\dfrac{df}{dt}+c_1+c_2\dfrac{df}{dx}+c_3\left(\dfrac{df}{dx}\right)^2+c_4\dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}+c_5f=0
$$
$$
c_0\dfrac{dg}{dt}-c_0\dfrac{dh}{dt}+c_1+c_2\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}-\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)+c_3\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}-\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)^2+c_4\left(\dfrac{d^2g}{dx^2}-\dfrac{d^2h}{dx^2}\right)+c_5(g-h) = 0
$$
Now expand quadratic term,
$$
=c_0\dfrac{dg}{dt}-c_0\dfrac{dh}{dt}+c_1+c_2\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}-\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)+c_3\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}\right)^2+2c_3\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}\right)\left(\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)+c_3\left(\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)^2+c_4\left(\dfrac{d^2g}{dx^2}-\dfrac{d^2h}{dx^2}\right)+c_5(g-h) = 0
$$
Define substitutions assuming $g$ and $h$ have same PDEs when impacted by $c_i$. At this point $c_1$ is determined.
$$
\dfrac{dg}{dt}=c_0\dfrac{dh}{dt},\quad c_1=a_1-b_1,\quad \dfrac{dg}{dx}=c_2\frac{b_2}{a_2}\dfrac{dh}{dx},\quad \dfrac{d^2g}{dx^2}=c_4\frac{b_4}{a_4}\dfrac{d^2h}{dx^2},\quad g=c_5\frac{b_5}{a_5}h
$$
Plugging in and simplifying yields
$$
c_0(c_0-1)\dfrac{dh}{dt}+c_1+c_2\left(c_2\frac{b_2}{a_2}-1\right)\dfrac{dh}{dx}+c_3\left(c_2\frac{b_2}{a_2}+1\right)^2\left(\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)^2+c_4(c_4-1)\dfrac{d^2h}{dx^2}+c_5(c_5-1)h = 0
$$
Now we have the system
$$
c_0\dfrac{df}{dt}+c_1+c_2\dfrac{df}{dx}+c_3\left(\dfrac{df}{dx}\right)^2+c_4\dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}+c_5f = 0
$$
$$
c_0(c_0-1)\dfrac{dh}{dt}+c_1+c_2\left(c_2\frac{b_2}{a_2}-1\right)\dfrac{dh}{dx}+c_3\left(c_2\frac{b_2}{a_2}+1\right)^2\left(\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)^2+c_4(c_4-1)\dfrac{d^2h}{dx^2}+c_5(c_5-1)h = 0
$$
The PDEs will match when
$$c_0=c_0(c_0-1),\quad c_1=c_1=a_1-b_1,\quad c_2=c_2\left(c_2\frac{b_2}{a_2}-1\right),\quad c_3=c_3\left(c_2\frac{b_2}{a_2}+1\right)^2,\quad c_4=c_4(c_4-1),\quad c_5=c_4(c_4-1)$$
We have
$$
c_0=c_4=c_5=2,\quad c_1=a_1-b_1,\quad c_2=2\frac{a_2}{b_2}
$$
But solving the $c_3$ term using $c_2$ yields $1=9$ which is false. So a solution does not exist using $\mathcal{D}$.

In short: take derivatives until your system of equations can be solved algebraically for $f$ and it's derivatives
Consider the simpler question: given the two first order PDEs $\psi(g,g_t,g_x)=0$ and $\varphi(h,h_t,h_x)=0$, with $f=\chi(g,h)$ can we find a PDE in terms of just $f$ and it's derivatives? Upon taking several derivatives of our equations we find the system
\begin{align}
&f=\chi(g,h),\quad f_x=\chi_1g_x+\chi_2h_x,\quad f_t=\chi_1g_t+\chi_2h_t,\\
&f_{xx}=\chi_1 g_{xx}+\chi_2h_{xx}+\chi_{11}g_x^2+\chi_{22}h_x^2+2\chi_{12}g_xh_x,\\
&f_{tt}=\chi_1 g_{tt}+\chi_2h_{tt}+\chi_{11}g_t^2+\chi_{22}h_t^2+2\chi_{12}g_th_t,\\
&f_{xt}=\chi_1 g_{xt}+\chi_2 h_{xt}+\chi_{11}g_xg_t+\chi_{22}h_xh_t+\chi_{12}(g_xh_t+g_th_x),\\
&\psi(g,g_t,g_x)=0,\quad \varphi(h,h_t,h_x)=0,\\
&\psi_1 g_x+\psi_2 g_{xt}+\psi_3 g_{xx}=0,\quad \psi_1 g_t+\psi_2 g_{tx}+\psi_3 g_{tt}=0,\\
&\varphi_1h_x+\varphi_2h_{xt}+\varphi_3h_{xx}=0,\quad \varphi_1h_t+\varphi_2h_{tt}+\varphi_3h_{xt}=0.
\end{align}
A system of 12 equations with 12 variables ($g$, $h$, and their derivatives) which we can eliminate in favor of $f$ and it's derivatives, $\Omega(f,f_x,f_t,f_{xx},f_{xt},f_{tt})=0$. In your case, we have $g_{xx}$ and $h_{xx}$ so we will require a derivative of higher order, though since $g_{xt}$, $g_{tt}$, $h_{xt}$, and $h_{tt}$ do not appear it may not turn out to require all 22 equations.

Thank you for your time and interest. A couple questions.  First, why do the second-order derivatives of $f$ have products of $g,h$ first-order derivatives? Is it because it's some principle required for general $f$, while unnecessary specifically for $f=g-h$?  Second, I appreciate your answer for the second-order generalized case, but for my specific $g,h$ PDEs with coefficients $a,b$, how can this be constrained or reduced further?  Intuition suggests most of the system goes away and the appropriate $a,b$ inform coefficients $\chi_{ij}$.

@Clayton The products occur for arbitrary function $\chi$, if $\chi=g-h$ then it is much simpler, that is correct. In your question you had said you are interested in problems where solving for $g$ and $h$ are impractical, so I thought a more generalized approach would be helpful when you try to apply it elsewhere. I have not gone through finding all 22 equations or seeing if some are unnecessary, it's a lot of writing! I lack the knowledge to see an easier course of action than simply going through with it.
